# Building Docker Image Programmatically Using Python Docker SDK without Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker

I am working on a Python project where I need to programmatically build a Docker image without using a Dockerfile. I want to use the Docker SDK for Python to achieve this.

Specifically, I would like to:

- Dynamically generate the image contents and configuration using Python code instead of writing a Dockerfile.
- Execute each Docker command separately, such as setting up the base image, copying files, installing dependencies, and running custom build commands.
- Retrieve the output or response from each Docker command execution for further processing or error handling.
- Finally, save the resulting changes as a new Docker image.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to approach this task using the Python Docker SDK. Any code examples or step-by-step instructions would be very helpful.

I have already installed the Docker SDK for Python using pip install docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when using the Docker API, you still need a Dockerfile. See [the Docker API reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.43/#tag/Image/operation/ImageBuild) for details, but briefly, a `POST` to the `/build` endpoint requires as input a tar-archive request body that includes a Dockerfile. The Docker daemon itself is responsible for unpacking the archive (the "build context") and generating the image.

It is *possible* to produce a Docker image without using Docker, but to do that you need to implement the OCI image spec yourself. See for example [Hashicorp Packer](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer) or [Buildah](https://buildah.io/) from the [Podman](https://podman.io/) folks.

Comment: "produce docker image without using docker" did you mean creating image without using docker right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. To be clear, I was providing examples of tools that produce Docker-compatible container images without using Docker itself.